# CouchDB views are getting timeout while fetching Data

Tags: couchdb-2.0, fauxton

I have 120k JSON records in CouchDB, where i have created 6 views under one design document. While accessing the view it gives me timeout error.

> (org.lightcouch.CouchDbException: << Status: 500 (Internal Server Error) {"error":"timeout","reason":"The request could not be processed in a reasonable amount of time."} )

CouchDB is installed on Linux environment with 8 cores and 27 GB of RAM.

i have set os_process_timeout=5000000 but still getting same error. Is there any way to avoid this timeout error?

i am getting same over on Fauxton Web Console.

Answer (score 0):

I have similar issue.

> couchdb error running query. reason: (timeout) the request could not be processed in a reasonable amount of time

But Im running coucdb on raspberry in docker container. I have removed constraints from couchdb container in  compose file.

```
resources:
  limits:
    cpus: '0.90'
    memory: 500M
```

But this "remove" doesnt help. I have only one view and only 170 docs ( Not thousand !)

The point is couchdb builds indexes during 2-3 mins. But during this time doesnt use all resources. (only 8 % cpu and 10% ram)

So my "solution" was to make another db, where I make changes every time, and replicate second db with first once a day. So index is build only once a day, and view is available during a day.

PS: no issues running the same db on 64bit arch in container thought.